# Regex is not working extracting key value pairs

Tags: java, regex, dictionary, youtube

I need to create a dictionary with key, value pairs based on the follow string as an example (youtube info_videos):

status=ok&use_cipher_signature=False&allow_ratings=1&iurlmaxres=http%3A%2F%2Fi.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2F5MwJobjESqw%2Fmaxresdefault.jpg&allow_embed=1&watermark=%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fs.ytimg.com%2Fyts%2Fimg%2Fwatermark%2Fyoutube_watermark-vflHX6b6E.png%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fs.ytimg.com

The problem is that my regex is not working all the time:

```
String pattern = "&(.+?)=(.+?)&.+?";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(decodedUrl);
Multimap<String, String> map = HashMultimap.create();
while(m.find()) {            
    map.put(URLDecoder.decode(m.group(1), "UTF-8"), URLDecoder.decode(m.group(2), "UTF-8"));
}
```

I Need help with my regex in java.

Comment: What are you trying to capture?

Comment: You'd better to split on `&` then on `=`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex.

```
(?:^|&)([^=]+)=([^&]+)
```

Answer (score 1):

I find that hwnd had the best answer because it is faster to do a negation like this [^=]+  and it avoids using lazy operators.

It could be a little bit easier without the ^ for the beginning:

```
&?([^=]+)=([^&]+)
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/uE1wO9/1)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this,

```
&(.+?)=(.+?)(?=&|$)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/iX8hF3/3)

The above regex would capture the key value pair in two separate groups. What it assumes that, a key must be preceded by a `&` symbol and the value must be followed by `&` or end of the line anchor. Use a lookahead to check whether the value is followed by `&` or `$`.

If you want to capture the first `status=ok` key value pair also then try the below regex,

```
(?<=&|^)(.+?)=(.+?)(?=&|$)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/iX8hF3/4)

Answer (score 0):

```
(.*?)=(.*?)(?=(?:&)|($))&?
```

You can use this.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/iX8hF3/6